# PostgreSQL PL/Python could not load library plpython3u

Tags: python, postgresql, loadlibrary, enterprisedb

I am trying to install the PL/Python extension for PostgreSQL. Executing the command `CREATE EXTENSION plpython3u;` results into the following error message:

```
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/lib/plpython3.dll": The specified module could not be found.
```

I have:

- double checked that the `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\lib\plpython3.dll` is present
- read the instruction bundled with my installation (doc/installation-notes.html). They mentioned the python version they have used to compile the binaries (Python 3.6.5)
- set the `PATH` to python version 3.6.8 (Python36_64, Python36_64/Scripts)
- downloaded embeddable Python version 3.6.5 added this version to the `PATH`
- double checked with both versions 3.6.8 and 3.6.5 that they were found by using this dependency checker [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) in both cases it has found the python36.dll
- tried 32 bit version of python but the [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) checker did not find the python dll so assuming it is using 64 bit.
- reopened powershell after each change I did to the `PATH` variable.

This is my `PATH`:

[image]

I am running:

```
                          version
------------------------------------------------------------
PostgreSQL 11.4, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

- Windows 10 Pro 64bit
- PostgreSQL EnterpriseDB installation

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by using a workaround by copying the python36.dll (3.6.8) into the system32 folder.

Answer (score -1):

First,you have to verify that python was installed correctly without any bugs,while installing python we have to choose customize installation instead of giving Install now,follow this method this will useful..